# How can i access certain res.data from async action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to access data received from web API to action in component. I set up registerUser action that posts new user data to API and then it is being sent to DB. API sents back status in JSON format. I want to render errors/notifications based on what was being passed as value of status key.

EDIT: I added key status in redux state, in REGISTER_USER type of action i am assigning value to it according to status being sent from backend.

However, i cannot access this propery in state by `this.props.state/this.props.user` - console loging it results in "undefined"

**authActions.js**

```
const authState = {
 users: [],
 status: ''
}

export const registerUser = user => dispatch => {
 axios.post('https://damianlibrary.herokuapp.com/users/register', user)
  .then(res => dispatch({
   type: REGISTER_USER,
   payload: res.data,
   status: res.data.status
  }))
}
```

**authReducer.js**

```
import { LOGIN_USER, REGISTER_USER } from '../actions/types';

const authState = {
 users: []
}

export default function(state = authState, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
  case LOGIN_USER:
   return {
    ...state
   };
  case REGISTER_USER:
   return {
    ...state,
    users: [action.payload, ...state.users]
   };
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

**RegistrationForm.js component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/authActions';

import './RegisterForm.css';

class RegisterForm extends Component {

 state = {
  user_name: '',
  password: '',
 }

 onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
 };

 onSubmitHandler = (e) => {

 const { user_name, password } = this.state

      const newUser = {
      user_name: user_name,
      password: password
    }
    this.props.registerUser(newUser)

    this.setState({
      user_name: '',
      password: ''
    })
  e.preventDefault();
}

render() {
const { user_name, password } = this.state;

return (
  <div className='formContainer'>
    <div className='form'>
      <form className='bookForm' onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this)}>
        <div className='inputs'>
          <input 
          type='text' 
          name='user_name'  
          placeholder='Username'
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          value={user_name}/>
          <input 
          type='password' 
          name='password'  
          placeholder='Password'
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          value={password}/>
        </div>
        <div className='buttonSpace'>
          <button>Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 user: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { registerUser })(RegisterForm);
```

Do i have to get such value in my App container (It is in ), then get status: state.status (redux state) and pass it via props to my RegisterForm component?

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
));

export default store;
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import bookReducer from './bookReducer';
import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
 book: bookReducer,
 auth: authReducer
});
```

Comment: Where are you adding your reducer to the store? Can you show that?. From what I'm seeing in this code, your RegistrationForm component is indeed connected to the redux store with react-redux, but I think the reducer is not connected to the store, so that's the reason it has a undefined value

Comment: I am adding it in rootReducer. Editted my question and provided store.js + rootReducer.js (it's name is index.js) @BenjamínVázquez

Comment: Ok, now I believe this is happening because the mapDispatchToProps cannot resolve state.user, it should be state.auth.user, I recommend you to change the function in order to before retrieve the object, add a console.log just to make sure

Comment: So, i should change mapStateTopProps -> mapDispatchToProps? When i tried user: state.auth.user console loging it also resulted it undefined.

Comment: Sorry!!! xD I was referring to mapStateToProps... and also I'd change your createStore func to a simplier one like this createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

Comment: Everything is working fine, but i have problem with status. I am assigning action.payload.status as a value to status key. After console logging (this.props) i am receiving empty string as value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185085/discussion-between-d-wasilewski-and-benjamin-vazquez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue. I called `auth: authReducer` in my **rootReducer.js** file and after that i tried to get what my reducer was returning by calling `user: state.user` instead of `user: state.auth`.

I can reach my redux state without any problems now.